# Multiply input from user in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to multiply two numbers from user and show the result in a separate box.
If the result is higher than 1000 or lower than 0 an alert should show.

And I thought I was on the right track, but it doesn't seem to be working.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
function multiply() {
    var number_1= document.getElementById("number_1").value;
    for (let i = 0; i > 1000; i++);

    var number_2= document.getElementById("number_2").value;
    for (let i = 0; i > 1000; i++);
    
    return (number_1 * number_2);
    
    if (result >1000) {
        alert("Detta blev tyvärr fel!");
    } else if (< 0) {
        alert("Detta blev tyvärr fel!")
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="number_1" value="" size="5"/> * 
        <input type="text" id="number_2" value="" size="5"/> = <span id="result"></span>
        <input onclick="multiply()" value="Ber&auml;kna" type="button"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You are returning values before alert statements please check again. It must be `var result = (number_1 * number_2);` in place of `return (number_1 * number_2);` and also the for loops are totally unnecessary for this so you can remove them.

Comment: Why 2 `for` loops? Logic error in function (`return` before `alert`). Syntax error in `else if`... Try to read any basic JS manual.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the previous comments, its function should be as follows:

```js
function multiply() {
    var number_1= document.getElementById("number_1").value;
    var number_2= document.getElementById("number_2").value;
    
    var result = 0;
    result = number_1 * number_2;

    if (result < 0 || result > 1000) {
        alert("Detta blev tyvärr fel!");
    }

    return result;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="number_1" value="" size="5"/> * 
        <input type="text" id="number_2" value="" size="5"/> = <span id="result"></span>
        <input onclick="multiply()" value="Ber&auml;kna" type="button"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```